# What does the spring.cloud.stream.source really do?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to understand how the new functional model of `Spring Cloud Streams` works and how the configuration actually works under the hood.

One of the properties I am unable to figure out is `spring.cloud.stream.source`.

What does this property actually signify ?

I could not understand the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources) :

> Note that preceding example does not have any source functions defined
> (e.g., Supplier bean) leaving the framework with no trigger to create
> source bindings, which would be typical for cases where configuration
> contains function beans. So to trigger the creation of source binding
> we use spring.cloud.stream.source property where you can declare the
> name of your sources. The provided name will be used as a trigger to
> create a source binding.

What if I did not need a `Supplier` ?

**What exactly is a source binding and why is it important ?**

What if I only wanted to produce to a messaging topic ? Would I still need this property ?

I also could not understand how it is used in the sample [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/0f579a8c95439e31aa4df130887aff382ed26c62/streambridge-samples/stream-bridge-avro/src/main/resources/application.properties#L17).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring cloud stream looks for `java.util` `Function<?, ?`, `Consumer<?>`, `Supplier<?>` beans and creates bindings for them.

In the supplier case, the framework polls the supplier (each second by default) and sends the resulting data.

For example

```java
@Bean
public Supplier<String> output() {
    return () -> "foo";
}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output-out-0.destination=bar
```

will send `foo` to destination `bar` each second.

But, what if you don't need a polled source, but you want to configure a binding to which you can send arbitrary data. Enter `spring.cloud.stream.source`.

```
spring.cloud.stream.source=output
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output-out-0.destination=bar
```

allows you to send arbitrary data to the stream bridge

```
bridge.send("output-out-0", "test");
```

In other words, it allows you to configure one or more ouput bindings that you can use in the `StreamBridge`; otherwise, when you send to the bridge, the binding is created dynamically.

Comment: Feel free to open an issue to ask for clarification https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues

Comment: If I want to send arbitrary data via the stream-bridge, then why even configure a `Supplier` bean ? I will just create a binding and use that binding to send the arbitrary data. I am still not convinced of the need for `spring.cloud.stream.source`.

Comment: What I mean is that I can do something like this: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myBinding.destination=myTopic`. And I can just use `myBinding` in `StreamBridge`. I don't even need `spring.cloud.stream.source`.

Comment: Also please note that [github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues) specifically notes that questions asking for clarification are strictly forbidden.

**Please ask questions about how to use something, or to understand why something isn't working as you expect it to, on Stack Overflow using the spring-cloud-stream tag.**

Comment: `destination` is a property that is applied to a binding; binding properties do not trigger the creation of a binding, they are used to customize it. Producer binding creation is triggered by one of three things - the presence of a `Supplier<?>` bean, or a `Function<?, ?>` bean, or the value of the `source` property. I am just telling you how it IS, I didn't design it (although I am not sure I would have done it any differently). I didn't suggest you ask for clarification in an ISSUE, I suggested you open one to request a change to the docs to make it clearer, if you think it's not clear.

Comment: Of course, the binding can be created dynamically on the first send (and the properties will be applied). The `source` is only needed if you want to create the binding during application initialization - i.e. to detect any misconfiguration then, rather than when you first send a message.

Comment: Opened the issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2226